# Delete a record if it exists in SQL SERVER 2018

Tags: sql-server

Good morning, I am having problems when I try to delete 1 record, when it exists, but when executing it only shows me the message but it does not delete it.

This is my query that I execute within a stored procedure where the parameters are sent from an application made in visual studies

```
if(@tipo=11)begin
    
        --execute AUTONORT_UBICACION_PRODUCTOS 9,'001','001','A','01','F','004','04A'
                        
        BEGIN TRY--en caso ocurra un error inesperado
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @FLAG_DELETE CHAR(1) = ''
            set @idUbicacion=RTRIM(@IDZONA)+RTRIM(@IDPAS)+'-'+RTRIM(@IDEST)+'-'+ltrim(rtrim(@IDFILCOL))
            

            if not exists(select u.IDUBICACION from PRODUCTO_UBICACION u where u.IDSUCURSAL=RTRIM(@IDSUC) and u.IDALMACEN=RTRIM(@IDALM) and u.IDPRODUCTO=RTRIM(@IDPRODUCTO))begin

                insert into PRODUCTO_UBICACION(idempresa,idsucursal,idalmacen,IDPRODUCTO,IDUBICACION,SINCRONIZA,FECHACREACION)            
                values(@IDEMP,RTRIM(@IDSUC),RTRIM(@IDALM),RTRIM(@IDPRODUCTO),@idUbicacion,'L',GETDATE())
            end 
            else begin
                    
                    SET @error = 'YA TIENE UNA ASIGNACION REGISTRADA''YA CUENTA CON UNA ASIGNACION REGISTRADA,PERO NO CUMPLE CON EL  ESTANDAR ... SE PROCEDERA A ELIMINA ESTE REGISTRO. 
                    INTENTE NUEVAMENTE LA ASGINACION DEL PRODUCTO'
                        DELETE  
                    FROM PRODUCTO_UBICACION 
                    WHERE IDSUCURSAL=RTRIM(@IDSUC) and IDALMACEN=RTRIM(@IDALM) and IDPRODUCTO=RTRIM(@IDPRODUCTO)
                raiserror(@error,16,1)
                return(99)  
                
                end
            
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
            
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH---mostrar mensaje de error de la transicion
                set @error=ERROR_MESSAGE()
                raiserror( @error,16,1)
    

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END CATCH
    end
```

Maybe I'm misapplying the syntax, any other ideas on how to perform this process.

Comment: Note there is no such version `SQL Server 2018`. Do you mean 2017 or 2019 maybe?

Comment: SQL SERVER 18.8

Comment: [SSMS versions](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2018/01/sql-server-management-studio-ssms.html) include an [18.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#188). SQL Server has [different versions altogether](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/). SSMS is the client you use to connect to the database server and is a different piece of software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RAISERROR` after the `DELETE` will enter the CATCH block and rollback the transaction. The `RETURN` statement after the `RAISERROR` will not be executed.

Comment: if I comment the raiserror then it no longer shows me the error message

Comment: @kenny, why did you comment out raiserror? I think you want to commit the transaction after the delete and then raiserror with your custom message. Change the catch block to `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK; THROW;`

Comment: what I want is that the @error message is displayed indicating that there is a record and from there I delete the record found.

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve with your idea.